# What's the point of dnsmasq in NetworkManager?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

I very recently came to realize that the caching is disabled by default on the dnsmasq that is integrated with NetworkManager. In my mind, that defeats the point and makes dnsmasq a redundant layer in name resolution.

Obviously, I must be missing something - *what is the purpose of dnsmasq in NM?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that switching nameservers is *annoying*. `/etc/resolv.conf` only gets read once when you start an application (technically when you do the first lookup), so if you change nameservers (because you moved from wireless to wired to 3g and back etc.), you will need to restart applications that need to look up names (such as browsers).

This is mitigated by using the local resolver, which does respond to these changes in a timely fashion, allowing applications to remain stupid and only query the nameserver on localhost.

Comment: That mostly brings up new questions. Why would an application read resolv.conf for name resolution? Shouldn't any user space application simply use the proper system calls (eg. gethostbyname()/getnameinfo()), so that yellow pages, files, dns servers or whichever name resolution services that are configured on the system, are queried in the defined order?

Comment: What do you think gethostbyname does? :) It doesn't contact anything magical that tells it names, it does the work of reading nsswitch.conf to find out which system to query, and, when querying dns, reads resolv.conf and does the querying.

Comment: I thought you meant that applications are now in the habit of bypassing nsswitch and going directly for resolv.conf. I certainly hope that's not the case. So, even if an application makes proper use of the system's name resolution, it might still only check resolv.conf on the first call or when the application is started?

Comment: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=resolv/res_libc.c;h=48d3200b7e2cd91314fbf56fca37ac41f6881927;hb=HEAD#l92

Comment: What that code says is "unless an application specifically requests reinitialization, I won't do it". No applications ever do this, as it's an unportable glibc implementation detail. And yes, I know this because it's bitten me badly. Lots of mysql servers that needed to be restarted because we were cleaning up our DNS infrastucture.

Comment: Right, so in essence dnmasq takes the role of a convenient abstraction layer for resolv.conf, making changes to name resolution more dynamic.

Comment: Come to think of it, dnsmasq also forces the use of the hosts file, even for any applications that do bypass nsswitch and head directly for DNS.

Answer (score 1):

From `man NetworkManager.conf` on 16.04, on the `dns` option:

> dnsmasq: NetworkManager will run dnsmasq as a local caching
> nameserver, using a "split DNS" configuration if you are connected
> to a VPN, and then update resolv.conf to point to the local nameserver.

So basically if you connect to a VPN, `NetworkManager` can instruct `dnsmasq` to use any VPN-specific DNS servers for required domains. This is impossible to do with just `resolv.conf`.

Comment: That is certainly an interesting use case. There it is again, though, the NM docs tend to say "caching nameserver", but the caching is in fact disabled by default. Go figure.